# What is the difference between ContentTemplate and Content of ContentPresenter in ComboBoxItem related ControlTemplate

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am not knowing what to use to override an existing template (either ContentTemplate, Content).  Imagine I have the following:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
.
.
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
.
.
<ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
```

What is the difference between "ContentTemplate" and "Content" in the above markup (also, what is good for what).

Also, where can I find more information on "TemplateBinding"?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Content` is generally used for your data.  It will be set to the `DataContext` of the your `ContentTemplate` `DataTemplate`.  The benefit of Content vs. ContentTemplate is the ability to change the ContentTemplate to display the same content in a different fashion.

[Template Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189062(VS.95).aspx)